# ASP.NET 4.0 Visual Studio Express - Parse error

Tags: asp.net, parsing

I am getting this after

1. compiling,
2. made sure bin directory has the compiled DLL files.

What am I missing?

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Parser Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'WebApplication1.WebForm1'.

Source Error:

```
Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>
Line 2:  <!DOCTYPE html>
Line 3:  Source File: /test/WebForm1.aspx    Line: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

check your namespace that is assigned to `WebForm1`.  When I encounter this error it's typically due to me changing the namespace and not updating the line in .aspx file.

It may look like

```
namespace MyRenamedNamespace
{
    public class WebForm1
    {
    }
}
```

in which case the line in the .aspx file should read

`<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyRenamedNamespace.WebForm1" %>`

Comment: Thanks - tried changing name and making it the same in the Inherits definition and the code. Did not work.  I wonder if this is a GoDaddy hosting issue.

Comment: have you tried running this locally on IIS?  That will give you better debug capabilities and help you isolate the issue to Godaddy or not.

Answer (score 0):

That means that the it cannot find the type/class of `WebApplication1.WebForm1`. I'd look in your code behind or `WebForm1.aspx.cs` and see if it looks something like:

```
namespace WebApplication1 {
    public class WebForm1 {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        }
    }
 }
```

I'd imagine your missing a namespace, or class name. If you can't find the code behind, I'd be tempted to recreate the page and Visual Studio should crate it for you.

Comment: Thanks Steven - tried changing name and making it the same in the Inherits definition and the code. Did not work. I wonder if this is a GoDaddy hosting issue. – user2547128 just now edit

Comment: With that error, I doubt it's a GoDaddy issue. Does it work locally?

Comment: Works perfectly  - locally. When I publish it, does not.

Comment: hmmm.. then maybe it is an issue on their end. It is possible their server isn't loading your assembly correctly. But I normally you get some other crazy error messages. I'd make sure you have the latest files from your /bin folder on GoDaddy. If that doesn't work, ask them to restart the application pool.

Comment: <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Codefile="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="newname.WebForm1" %>

Comment: I just changed the Codebehind to Codefile - and copied the file over to the GoDaddy server.  That made it work - whew!  Looks like there is some issue with the way Codebehind is being handled at GoDaddy server. Thank you all for your help.